# I tried to move to a different career track, but I'm back to my old one. What should I put in the CV

Tags: software-industry, resume, career-switch

I worked as a software engineer since beginning of 2013 in a couple of companies. In 2019 I decided to try my luck in Data Scientist role in a new company (A). I didn't liked it, so - feeling it may be a problem with the company, not a role - after a couple of months I moved for Data Scientist role in yet another company (B). Again I didn't liked it, and decided perhaps data science career is not for me - so I moved to Software Engineer role in another company (C). In total I worked as a data scientist for around a year - (5+8 months).

How detailed should I be when putting my experience as a data scientist in my CV? Can I merge my whole experience into one "Data Scientist" CV position, and mentioned that I worked in this time for a different companies and multiple projects? Obviously I feel one position for above one year looks much better than showing on my CV I changed job twice after only a couple of months.

Comment: The main question here is: do I need to mention I spend 5 months in first company, 8 months in the other, or is "I spent 13 months as Data Scientists working for a couple of projects" enough info?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere IMO your comment would qualify as an answer ;)

Comment: I feel you, I'm doing the same thing right now, I've almost totally eliminated all references to an IBM tool that I use in my current job to prevent recruiters from seeing only that. (very few people know the tool in my city and those who use it are rare goods).

Answer (score 5):

Depends on the construct of the entire CV (chronological vs functional).

If the rest of your CV shows each job (chronological), then you shouldn't combine these two jobs into one. It would look out of place as best, and misleading at worst.

If the rest of your CV only shows general periods of time in each role, rather than listing specific jobs (functional), then it might make sense to collapse these two jobs into one role.

I wouldn't write a functional resume/CV, as I think they are less effective, but you may like them.

For me, in a chronological resume/CV, I would write less about roles that don't fit with the job I am seeking in order to de-emphasize them, but still include those jobs. I don't like to leave gaps that would require elaborate explanations.

Answer (score 0):

> How detailed should I be when putting my experience as a data
> scientist in my CV?

If you are not applying for Data Scientist roles, then you'll still want to include the experience in these roles but only include the Software Engineering / Development aspects of the jobs.

> Can I merge my whole experience into one "Data Scientist" CV position,
> and mentioned that I worked in this time for different companies and
> multiple projects?

I would keep your CV in chronological order as companies are more interested in gaps of missing employment other than positions held. For me, it wouldn't flow. Keep the descriptions of the job focused on the job you're applying to, with less being more if there aren't many similarities.

> Obviously, I feel one position for above one year looks much better
> than showing on my CV I changed job twice after only a couple of
> months.

You can easily explain that you wanted to give Data Engineering for you after your long stint as a Software Developer but give it a go and it wasn't for you. Then further explain how much you are looking forward to moving towards a Software Engineer role again as it's where your passion is. (Or alternative reason why you're applying for X Y Z job.